# При отправке json на сервер через post получаю 405 ошибку Android

Tags: android, json, post

Делаю запрос такого вида в комментах пробовал различные варианты передачи запроса, ничего не помогает выдает 405 ошибку, я все думаю что неверное подаю входные данные, но скорей всего ошибка в коде. Помогите кто может.

```
 URL url = new URL("http://176.112.199.219:333/");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);

            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            jsonParam.put("email", email);
            jsonParam.put("password", password);

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("email", email)
                    .appendQueryParameter("password", password);
            String urlParameters  = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
//          String urlParameters = jsonParam.toString();
//          String urlParameters = "email="+email+"&"+"password="+password;
//          String urlParameters =  "login=" + URLEncoder.encode("Test@test.ru", "UTF-8") +"&"+
//               "password=" + URLEncoder.encode("Test", "UTF-8");

            OutputStream dStream = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(dStream, "utf-8"));
//          dStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
//          dStream.flush();
//          dStream.close();
//          writer.write(jsonParam.toString());
            writer.write(urlParameters);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println("Sending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    final String email = "Test@test.ru";
final String password ="test";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте начать с правильного url'a :)

```
http://176.112.199.219:333/v1/auth
```

Comment: Просто весь день мучался, вот так вот взял и помог)) спасибо все заработало)) Правда не особо понял как ты достал этот путь я его в упор не вижу

Comment: http://176.112.199.219:333, если перейти по это ссылки в самом верху подпись /v1, ну а дальше выбираешь, что тебе нужно /auth или к примеру метод GET /user? пишеться так 'http://176.112.199.219:333/v1/users?'

Comment: Разобрался спасибо!